# identifying email issue

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to identify and extract emails from sentences. sample example sentences with emails.

```
sen1 = "Please send an email to joe@gmail.com"
sen2 = "reply to us on raady_07@hotmail.co.kr"
sen3 = "mailing address: raady.07@yahoo.co.se"
```

I tried using information from [this link](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=email&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression), and found one expression working for sen1 and sen2

```
re.findall('\w+?@\w+?\x2E.+', sen1)
```

I have no problem in identifying for sen1 and sen2. but for sen3 the email has '.' between, so i tried with many trails

```
re.findall('\w+?\x2E.+@\w+?\x2E.+', sen3)
re.findall('([-!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~]+(\.[-!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~]+)*|"([]!#-[^-~ \t]|(\\[\t -~]))+")@[0-9A-Za-z]([0-9A-Za-z-]{0,61}[0-9A-Za-z])?(\.[0-9A-Za-z]([0-9A-Za-z-]{0,61}[0-9A-Za-z])?)+', sen3)
re.findall( ,sen3)
```

I could not even understand what the complicated expression is doing, it returns an empty list ([]) even for sen1 and sen2. how to identify such emails as in sen3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
\S+@\S+
```

and verify later if the address *actually exists*, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/mK6bBE/1/).

Comment: you are just awesome.